# Onclick event for li with javascript in asp.net mvc

Tags: onclick, html-lists

```
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model.Users.Where(s => s.DepartmentId == 3))
{
<li>
@Ajax.ActionLink(item.UserName, "Index", new { item.Id }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Get" });
</li>
}
</ul>
```

How can ı get item.Id if i onclick item.username with javascript ?

I thought give to attribute to "li onclick".but i dont know there is better solution here or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a standard link and data-* attribute:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Users.Where(s => s.DepartmentId == 3))
    {
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink(
                item.UserName, 
                "Index", 
                new { id = item.Id },
                new { @class = "myLink", data_id = item.Id }
            )
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

and then in a separate javascript file:

```
$(function() {
    $('.myLink').click(function() {
        // get the id:
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        alert(id);

        // now you can send the AJAX request
        $.get(this.href);

        // cancel the default action of the link
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: `$.get(this.href)` is sending an AJAX request to the controller action. So all you have to do is have your controller action take this id parameter: `public ActionResult Index(string id) { ... }`

Comment: i put breakpoint than there is nothing between controller and function.İf i click anyusername nothing happened

Comment: Try inspecting the AJAX request in your javascript debugging toolbar. For example if you are using Google Chrome you could activate debugging tools wit `F12` and then look at the Network tab. Can you see the AJAX request being sent to your controller? Have you referenced jQuery in your page? Are there some javascript errors in the console? Learn to debug your code.